# CSS for Print media to show running page on specific pages

Tags: html, css, printing

Is there a way to create a CSS style for print media that generates a running head only on specific pages of a document?

Running head that appears on every page is possible:

```
div.divHeader {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

But what if one wanted to show different headers on different pages (e.g., beginning of a chapter, or different running head for different chapters etc)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to use PHP. Then you can do a script that check what page the user is on and takes the header for that page. If you only use HTML and CSS maybe you can set a class on the body for each document and then style it the way you want?

Ex:  page start:

```
<html>
<body class="first">
content here
</body>
</html>
```

ex: page two

```
<html>
<body class="second">
content here
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Interesting, are you suggesting to render a series of html pages in a single document? I am using php so that's a possibility.

Comment: hm just tried it, but the problem is due to the "fixed" property of the style class, the running head will be overlaid on every page

Comment: Can you please give a sample of your code? So I can see more exact what you're aiming for?